# How to make Thunar regenerate thumbnails?

Tags: thunar, thumbnails

I have a large collection on pictures which needed cropping, color balancing, autotuning, etc. Now Thunar is showing the old thumbnails and is very confusing because i can't visually separate edited pictures from unedited ones. How can i make Thunar automatically regenerate or create new thumbnails for the edited pictures?

Comment: Have you tried simply refreshing?

Comment: I tried refreshing multiple times, i tried log out, i tried even rebooting PC. No change. Just the same old thumbnails.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Remove all contents of `~/.cache/thumbnails/normal`:

```
rm ~/.cache/thumbnails/normal/*
```

...and refresh the folder in thunar.

Comment: It works, but i just had to individually confirm the deletion of some files with very long names. I kept on pressing Y (for yes) and Return for like a dozen times. Is there any way to make a recurrent answer for that, like `-y` or something?

Comment: Add the -f option, @ipselute.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting `~/.cache/thumbnails/*` didn't seem to help in my case, I had to regenerate thumbnails by refreshing (`Ctrl`+`r`) each view in Thunar.  That is, having the first set of files in view in Thunar, refresh, then scroll and select a file not in view, refresh, etc. until all files have been in view while refreshing.  Of course it's faster if you zoom out (`Ctrl`+`-`) to have more files in view.

It worked for JPGs, but the older thumbnails kept attached to raw (.NEF) files.

I ended up using this more radical solution :

```
rm $(locate thumbnails)
```

Answer (score 0):

Its required to delete both normal and large thumbnails:

```
find ~/.cache/thumbnails/ -type f -print -delete
```

`-print` will print list of deleted files and can be removed.