# How to reset thumbnail cache in XFCE?

Tags: 20.04, xfce, thumbnails, thunar

I had a lot of plots (in pdf format) in a directory. Recently, I had regenerated all the plots (retaining their previous names).

Now, Thunar shows distorted thumbnails for many of these regenerated plots. I tried the following, but they did not work.

1. I renamed the directory.
2. I disabled thumbnails in Thunar preferences, and re-enabled them.

**How to reset all the thumbnails, and make the computer generate them again?**

I am using Xubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Possibly related:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/800070/how-to-make-thunar-regenerate-thumbnails