# thunar regenerate thumbnail for a single image

Tags: xubuntu, thumbnails, thunar

I see there is a solution to regenerate all image thumbnails, but what if I do not want to regenerate all thumbs, but just for one image.

the thing is, that if I rotate an image using for example: ''' mogrify -rotate 90 imgname ''' the thumbnail does not rotate, And I do not want to delete all the thumbnail for only one image as it is described in this post: [How to make Thunar regenerate thumbnails?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/800070/how-to-make-thunar-regenerate-thumbnails)